# How to prompt Safari 14.1 bookmark changes?

Tags: safari, data-synchronization, bookmarks

Two Macs are both running updated Catalina.  Safari bookmarks that are added to one machine are automagically updated on the other, because of the same AppleID.

Bookmarks were organized into folders this morning on machine one: Is there a procedure to prompt machine two to update the bookmarks per machine one?

I am assuming that bookmark changes (organization of bookmarks into folders) are somehow synchronized and that it is reasonable to expect that the bookmarks on both machines will be organized identically.